# Add Symfony Assert in Entity Callback

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

How to add Symfony Assert (Notblank() ; Number() ; Email() ; ...) in entity callback ?

Example `AppBundle\Entity\TrainingLead` :

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function rejectedValidate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if (null !== $this->rejectedAt) {
        // How to add "Assert\NotBlank()" in rejectedContent" ?
        $context->buildViolation('training_lead.reason')
            ->atPath('rejectedContent')
            ->addViolation()
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use validation groups?, you can change your groups dynamically: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/validation_group_service_resolver.html

Comment: If you don't want to use it on property itself and you really want to check if property is blank on the callback, why not just use if statement?